# How to show a modal only over a containerview, and not the whole view

Tags: ios, swift, modal-dialog, uicontainerview

I need to show a modal on top of my containerview, and still be able to use the functions in the mainview. But when I add the modal (transparent), it fills the while view, and then my buttons aren't able to be touched. Is it possible to only show the modal in top of my containerview, and not as a "whole" view?
I'm making the segue to the modal from my containerview-class, hence I thought it would only take up the space allocated for the containerview.

Help me please ;)

Comment: A "modal" view means it has full control. If you want to show a view over part of the screen, while allowing elements on the rest of the screen to be interacted with, then you do not want to show a "modal" view. Simply create  a new view and add it as a subview on top of the "container view" ... the rest of the screen will still be available for tapping buttons, etc.

Comment: That was what I ended up doing :) Thanks for your anwser!